# Vimspector how to define prelaunch task

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim, ide

I am trying out Vim as a C++ ide using `puremourning/vimspector` and `ycm-core/YouCompleteMe` plugins as the debugger/launcher/error checker, etc. My project directory is thus:

```
--myproject\
    ----src\
        main.cpp (includes maininclude in include folder)
    ----include\
        maininclude.h (included in main in src folder)
    ----.vscode\ (all vscode .json files reside inside this folder)
        tasks.json
        launch.json
        Makefile
        Makefile-Debug
        Makefile-impl
        Makefile-variables
    ----.vim\ (all vim ide related files ideally should reside here)
        .ycm_extra_conf.py
        Makefile
        Makefile-Debug
        Makefile-impl
        Makefile-variables
    .vimspector.json
```

1. Is there a way to have `vimspector` reference the `.vimspector.json` file from inside the `.vim\` folder instead of directly below `myproject\` folder? For instance, is there a setting equivalent to the following (which works for `YouCompleteMe`) that should be placed inside of `.vimrc` ?

   `let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf ='./.vim/.ycm_extra_conf.py'`
   which changes the default location from where this configuration file is read ?

The reason is that I would like all vim-ide related files to be fully contained within `.vim\` folder and not in the outside project folder.

2. `.vimspector.json` file seems similar in content to `.vscode/launch.json` file. My `.vscode/launch.json` file has an option of a `preLaunchTask` which builds the project.

`"preLaunchTask": "lindbgbuild",`

This build task does nothing other than the following:

```
"command": "make",
"args": ["CONF=Debug", "-C", "./.vscode"],
```

Also, within VSCode, building automatically saves any source code files that have changed but not yet saved. The net effect of all of this is that within VSCode, it is straightforward to change a file, setup a breakpoint and run it (if there are errors, in this process, VSCode automatically indicates where the error is and the debug launch is aborted) to hit that breakpoint with a single button press (`F5`). Note the `-C ./.vscode` option. This allows me to start VSCode from `myproject\` folder and accesses the makefiles within `myproject\.vscode\` folder. All of this is highly convenient.

Is a similar feature available in `vimspector` that automatically saves the file, if changed, builds it using make from within `.vim\` folder `Makefile`s, and then launches the debugger until the breakpoint is hit? As of now, because of my inability to use this feature (assuming it exists), I am having to separately navitage to `\myproject\.vim\` and issue `make CONF=Debug`, then go back into Vim and then hit `F5`.

Comment: Answered by maintainer of ycm and vimspector here: https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector/issues/276 and https://github.com/puremourning/vimspector/issues/275